# BIOS of my laptop loading too slow

Tags: laptop, performance, bios

I have Dell Vostro 1710 17" and its BIOS for unknown problems takes more then 1minutes to load when my OS loads in less then 15seconds.

Any suggestions to resolve the problem would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I know this should be obvious... but did you try updating the BIOS?

Comment: Yes, I updated several times, but without any results.

Comment: Did you reset the BIOS to default settings?

Answer (score 2):

Well, all in all, 1 minute 15 seconds isn't a very bad boot time, but still, I can understand it being annoying!

First things, check for any BIOS update on Dell's support site that have been released since you bought the laptop.

Next, try to work out why it is taking so long - press <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> in order to see the text.

If you have a lot of memory, it could be the memory check. It could also be scanning for drives/USB devices.

All I can suggest is looking in the BIOS options and see if there is any options for Quick Boot / Disable Memory check and the often forgotten, make sure that you set your hard drive to the primary boot device (and disable network boot).

Comment: I have Quick Boot enabled by default and there is no any options about disabling memory check. I have 4Gb of memory.